# python basic uppercase and lowercase string

Tags: python, string, list-comprehension

I'm trying to change all the uppercase characters to lowercase and vice versa, in a given string.

- What am I doing wrong, why isn't my code working?

So I'm trying to loop through each letter( which is s) and changing it to upper if it's lower "and" vice versa.

```
string='HeLLO'

result=list(s.upper() for s in string if s.lower() and s.lower() for s in string if s.upper())

print(result)

output: ['H', 'E', 'L', 'L', 'O', 'H', 'E', 'L', 'L', 'O', 'H', 'E', 'L', 'L', 'O', 'H', 'E', 'L', 'L', 'O', 'H', 'E', 'L', 'L', 'O']
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`if s.lower()` it is bad condition since it is just function to lower characters, same with `if s.upper()`. Use `s.isupper()` instead.

```
>>> print result = list((s.lower() if s.isupper() else s.upper() for s in string))
['h', 'E', 'l', 'l', 'o']
```

And your logic with generators is wrong:

> **s.upper() for s in string if s.lower()** `and` *s.lower() for s in string if s.upper()*

First part is generator with condition - it is ok apart from `if s.lower()`.

Second part is generator too.

Now it is just complex conditon for first generator ( `if` ... `and` ...)

Comment: you are using a boolean test on s.lower() which is always True, so you always perform the s.upper() operation

Comment: @BlivetWidget So if s.lower() is True ( meaning if characters are lowercase) then we would change them to s.upper? Isn't that what this line is doing: s.upper() for s in string if s.lower()

Comment: @xi_ Thanks man. But again, could you please explain what my code is doing step by step? Like what's wrong with my logic originally

Comment: @Angular, s.lower() does NOT tell if the string is lowercase.  It makes the string lowercase.  Because this is not an empty string, it will evaluate to boolean True.

Answer (score 3):

There is already a method for this.

```
s = 'HelLo'
print(s.swapcase())

'hELlO'
```

Answer (score 1):

> What am I doing wrong, why isn't my code working?

While good python code can look like (executable) pseudo code and read much like English, just stating what you want to do in English and expecting Python to do the right thing won't work. ;-)

In particular, keyword `and` in

```
s.upper() for s in string if s.lower() and s.lower() for s in string if s.upper()
```

doesn't do what you probably think it would do. `and` is a boolean operator, which works like this:

```
True and True == True
True and False == False
False and True == False
False and False == False
```

Using it on strings (as you do here) will yield a maybe surprising results:

```
"foo" and "bar" == "bar"
"" and "bar" == ""
```

See the other answers for what to do instead.

Comment: oh... Dam it haha, I tried using plain english to python logic... Fail. Thanks